# overlapping intervals in a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to work on genomic data with R, and I have seen a couple of topics with quite good answers related to two dataframes and overlapping intervals. My problem is that I have one dataframe with overlapping intervals, which I would like to  merge, i.e:

```
chrom   start   stop
 5       100     105
 5       100     105
 5       200     300
 9       275     300
 9       280     301
```

I would like to end up with something like this:

```
chrom   start   stop
 5       100     105
 5       200     300
 9       275     301
```

I am also trying to become better at coding, so I was wondering what would be the most elegant way to do it. Hope this is not redundant with some other query,

Comment: data.table::foverlaps

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Using [GenomicRanges](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GenomicRanges.html)::reduce:

```
require(GenomicRanges)
as.data.frame(reduce(GRanges(df$chrom, IRanges(df$start, df$stop))))
#   seqnames start end width strand
# 1        5   100 105     6      *
# 2        5   200 300   101      *
# 3        9   275 301    27      *
```

It's also possible using `data.table::foverlaps` or `GenomicRanges::findOverlaps`, but not as straightforward.

Comment: My guess it's just `setkey(setDT(df)) ; unique(foverlaps(df, df), by = "i.stop")`, no?

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm :-) You introduced me to quite a nice set of tools

Comment: For me the default of `min.gapwidth=1L` was absolutely unexpected so it took a while to narrow down some interval merges I couldn't explain. (Without knowing anything about the topic) I guess it's appropriate for genomic data but anyone else might want to set `min.gapwidth=0L`.

Comment: If anyone wonders how to limit the merging to overlaps with e.g. 60%: I didn't find a trivial way like extending the reduce function but by providing certain `seqnames` to the `GRanges` function you can make sure that only similar ranges are merged. E.g. setting `seqnames` to the mean of the range and cutting off a few digits. Multiple conditions are possible by `paste()`ing.